# The Complier is inserting $ when i just want it as it is

Tags: math-mode, text

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
            $
l.434       \item  "\backslash
                           S"
?
```

I received this error message when i ran pdflatex command in cmd.exe
I want the output as it is. This is my latex code.

```
\item "\backslash s" 
 to find whitespace
```

Comment: unrelated to the error but you should not use `"` in latex it produces inconsistent results depending on the encoding  better to use `\`\`...'' ` that is two back quotes and two single quotes not the `"` character

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\backslash` is a math mode command, like `\sqrt`, you want `\textbackslash`